# Cannot access ASP.NET Core Web API from Windows-based Amazon virtual machine

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been searching Google and StackOverflow about this for several hours now, and nothing seems to work.

I created a Web API server in ASP.NET Core and verified it works locally.

I created a new EC2 VM to host the Web API. I copied all the binaries for the API up to EC2, and started the server from the command line.

I have made sure that the required EC2 security group exists and that the correct TCP port is open for Input in the security group.

I have added an appropriate firewall rule to Windows firewall.

NETSTAT -Q shows that the server is working and that the port is in LISTENING mode.

I get the public IP address for my EC2 VM and go back to my local machine.

I use POSTMAN to submit POST requests to the EC2-based server.
POSTMAN returns an error: "There was an error connecting to ...."

So I'm at a loss as to what to do next. Have I missed some EC2 configuration? Is there something else I have to do to the ASP.NET Core WebAPI code?

Comment: Can you paste the full error description. Also, are you trying to deploy it on Windows server based EC2 instance? If yes, have you ensured that server has ASP.NET Core hosting bundle installed?

Comment: Here's what Postman displays (I've altered the IP address for security): Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://ec2-1x-5x-1xx-2xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/api/Authenticate.

Comment: I'll check into the core hosting bundle issue right now...

Comment: I used dotnet publish to create a self-hosting executable, i.e. IIS and IISExpress not required. Everything works locally, i.e. I run the exe and use a separate program to access the Web API, but the same process does not work when hosted in EC2

Comment: Although you have a self hosting executable, you still require a process manager and reverse proxy server for receiving http requests.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.2
Also, have you checked that server is listening on port 80? Are you able to access `http://ec2-1x-5x-1xx-2xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` without any port?

Comment: So, I installed Postman on EC2 and re-ran the test locally on EC2. I start up the server from the command line (it's self-hosting, so any form of IIS is not required, reverse proxy not necessary here). Server is listening on port 5000 (not 80 or 8080). Anyway when all is local, it all works as it should. So, to my mind, its just the configuration of EC2 ports that is problematic, but I cannot see why.